# Pre-trained shallow CNN with Imagenet

Tags: neural-networks, pre-training

For my research I need some pre-trained model shallower than VGG-16.

Resnet, facenet won't be useful. I found VGG-11 but is there anything else? 
What are some pre-trained shallow CNN based on image dataset?

[vgg1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05746.pdf)

Comment: How about the 7-layer AlexNet?

Comment: If computation speed and model size are an issue, why not try a MobileNet?

Answer (score 1):

Please try **AlexNet**.

#### keras

However, unlike VGG16, I could not find AlexNet in keras. Nevertheless, you can download pre-trained weights from various sources and use it to train.
It contains 5 convolutional layers and 3 fully connected layers. You can download AlexNet weights from this [link](https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras#get-the-weights-of-the-pre-trained-networks).

#### PyTorch

Consider using PyTorch if you would like to use pre-built bundle as shown in code below.

```
import torchvision.models as models
alexnet_model = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
```

Architecture as shown below:
[image]

Reference: 
[1](https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras#get-the-weights-of-the-pre-trained-networks) https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras#get-the-weights-of-the-pre-trained-networks